# Is there any way to know whether a highchart DOM is complete rendered?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am injecting JS code to a website with HighChart on it. And my code is going to use `html2canvas` to take a `snapshot` of that chart.

However, sometimes, the charts have animation so that I shouldn't capture the canvas too soon.

So an easy way is to set a `setTimeout` to wait for the chart.

But is there any other way that I can know when the chart's animation is exactly finished?

The website uses Highcharts 5. And I don't have access to its JavaScript file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, you can catch animation `event` and set `complete` function.

```
chart: {
    animation: {
       complete: () => console.log('animation completed'),
    }
},
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            animation: {
                complete: () => console.log('animation complete'),
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6gp7vfde/

I had the same issue when I was taking PDF with PhantomJS.

Comment: Just wondering, as an injected code, how can I access its `chart:{}` object? The only access I have is the DOM like `$('#chart')[0]`. All the set-up process for that chart was done in its inner functions, which are not able to be seen through `window.` scope.

Comment: inject `window.myCallback` and in the `complete` function do something like `if (window.myCallback) { window.myCallback(); } else { console.log('callback called to early'); }`

Comment: How can I inject that in the `complete` function as the `complete` function is in the file that I can't access/change.

Comment: Why can't you change that file? It's client side, unless it is highly compressed source, you most likely can change that source before it's execution. This is another topic, which means another question, if I were you I would provide some executable code in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it is a highly compressed code and the highchart is created in a anonymous function. That is why I want to know whether there is any clue from the DOM. Just hope HighChart would add some `data-render="done"` stuff to its root node.

Comment: @AGamePlayer I have told you already: this is another question. What happen on the client side is totally under your control, there is a way, and that way may be harder than using `setTimeout` but it is still the same. Edit the source using a script, rexecute the page with your edition, compressed or not, this is possible, but it might take time. Can you please create another question for this? I might have a look, but please include code sample.